# SD corrupted / data loss when renaming files with Raspberry

Tags: bash, raspberry-pi, udev

For my parents I try to convert the names of files on a (micro-)SD-card with a Raspberry. But many times the SD-card get corrupted or big files get removed from the card while renaming the file. This is the UDEV rule I use:

```
ACTION=="add", 
SUBSYSTEM=="block", 
ATTRS{idVendor}=="14cd", 
ATTRS{idProduct}=="121f", 
RUN+="/home/pi/bashtest.sh"
```

And this is the code in bash on the Raspberry:

```
    #!/bin/bash
{
sudo umount /dev/sda1
sudo fsck -y /dev/sda1
} &
{
dd=1234567890aAbBcCdDeEfFgGhHiIjJkKlLmMnNoOpPqQrRsStTuUvVwWxXyYzZ
sleep 5
sudo mount -t vfat /dev/sda1 /media/usb1
cd /media/usb1/DCIM/Camera
sudo find /media/usb1/DCIM/Camera -regextype posix-egrep -regex ".*[^/]{13}.JPG"|
for i in *.JPG
do
ddate=$(exiv2 "${i}"|grep timestamp)
SPEC=$ddate
read X X YEAR MONTH DAY HOUR MINUTE SECOND <<<${SPEC//:/ }
d1=${YEAR:2}
d2=${dd:(10#$MONTH-1):1}
d3=${dd:(10#$DAY-1):1}
d4=${dd:(10#$HOUR-1):1}
d5=${dd:(10#$MINUTE-1):1}
d6=${dd:(10#$SECOND-1):1}
d7=0
/media/usb1/DCIM/"${d1}${d2}${d3}${d4}${d5}${d6}${d7}.JPG"
sudo mv -u "$i" /media/usb1/DCIM/"${d1}${d2}${d3}${d4}${d5}${d6}${d7}.JPG"
done
for i in *.MP4
do

dddate=$(exiftool "${i}" |grep "Media Create Date" | awk -F':' '{print $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7}')
SPEC=$dddate
read YEAR MONTH DAY HOUR MINUTE SECOND <<<${SPEC//:/ }
d1=${YEAR:2}
d2=${dd:(10#$MONTH-1):1}
d3=${dd:(10#$DAY-1):1}
d4=${dd:(10#$HOUR-1):1}
d5=${dd:(10#$MINUTE-1):1}
d6=${dd:(10#$SECOND-1):1}
d7=0
sudo mv  -u "$i" /media/usb1/DCIM/"${d1}${d2}${d3}${d4}${d5}${d6}${d7}.MP4"
/media/usb1/DCIM/"${d1}${d2}${d3}${d4}${d5}${d6}${d7}.MP4"
done
sudo umount -l /media/usb1
sleep 5
sudo shutdown -h now
} &
```

With the first program I let a copy in an other map, but that took too much space of the SD-card. Any ideas how I could improve the code?

This is a trail of a previous program:

https://vimeo.com/86546119

Comment: can't you just take the SD-card to a "real" PC and process it there? Good luck!

Comment: Good luck with renaming more than 100 files automaticly to a 8 character name. And than you also need to take a laptop together with your Ipad to be able to copy the pictures. But thanks for the thought.

Answer (score 1):

A common problem with raspberry pi. Solutions range from changing to better power supply, using a different SD card, and reducing CPU clock, especially if overclocked. Problem with "charger" style power supplies is often that their response to pulse load is poor, causing very short brownouts during flash writes.

Comment: Hmm. tricky thing. My parents use a micro-sd to make the pictures. I don't know the stability for that. Maybe I can look for a better power supply. The CPU is not overclocked.

Comment: I may add "board modification: buffer power routes with pairs of capacitors - electrolytic and ceramic - filtering out the load spikes" as another potential solution. The board resetting when plugging/unplugging USB device is an indicator of the same power problem.